# Generally Occult-Themed Horrifyingly Infernal Cryptic Crossword

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

This is a themed cryptic crossword, with the theme in either the clue or the answer. The theme is loosely 'gothic horror', with some exceptions for other spooky stuff that fit well.

Beware! There is at least one [Printer's Devilry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printer%27s_Devilry) and at least one [Composite Anagram](https://www.crosswordunclued.com/2011/01/composite-anagrams.html) somewhere inside.

[image: empty cryptic crossword, with no description available]

### Across:

1, 28. Out cold after making reservations for nobleman (perhaps a Transylvanian) (4,3,3,5)

6, 29. Neat following for family radio stations in Hawaii (4 and 4)

10. Separate and Extract total energy e.g. from a poltergeist, gently? (5)

11. Phantom pen crossing out a character with the beginnings of Howard Lovecraft ending avoided in The Pearl of Asia (5, 4)

12, 22. Film, Silent, (no English). In it a word of action, for all to see: "Hand the French a solution to everything" (6, 6)

13. Morticia with cousin turned back? See yours truly leaving with early player? (6)

14. Byron's Poem a succulent piece of history. (8)

16. See 15dn.

18. Palm reading reveals affair (6)

20. Sang perhaps of Lenore, reviving dead ball (8)

22. See 12ac.

23. Gothic novelist and doctors assistant? That might be why limbs are missing. (6)

27. Cursed down dale, and up hill without odd dawn I might correspond to something natural. (5,4)

28. See 1ac.

29. And 6ac.

30. Lacking picture restorer, he created the portrait curse (unwittingly) to remain alive against all odds (5, 5)

### Down:

1. Gives a drug to perform seances! Spare the cane please. (5)

2. Sir Isaac & Spooner's resistance circle victorious. (7)

3. Tragic victors heart inserted into fantastical shell (5)

4. Re: Pleaides, Poe (Henri, lately) leaves and makes another bargain. (8)

5. See 25dn.

7. Chilling selection for lobotomy technique? (7)

8.  Mostly end hears'y, some dead scattered within and lowered into coffin. (9)

9. Hedonistic model taken in; Dorian Grey perhaps and might be way to 30ac. (8)

14. Barker with alchemy, lies here forgotten, but another on trial was released after repining neck cloth. (4, 5)

15. Get ready to kill vampire, it's how one increases risk (5,3,6)

17. Carriage accident reveals mysterious individual, leaving Laura amorous, sinisterly and seen in a glass darkly. (8)

19. Bright framing of ghostly needlewoman? What devilry is this? (7)

21. Felix and Bella: "Perhaps flowers, including a Lily and the other side of the rose, have a sublime range of colours?" (7)

24. Perhaps blood in drinks, shirts or boots, placed disquietingly? (5)

25., 5. Search perhaps conducted by the press? (5-4)

26. Silent episode featuring gentlemen with human-ish exterior. (4)

Comment: Pretty sure "repining" in 14d should be "repinning".

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan that's what I thought, but various spell checkers disagreed with me. Happy to fix it now I've got someone to back me up! 

Comment: "Repining" is a thing but means something else. I think your word would usually be "re-pinning" rather than "repinning".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Slightly partial answer**

I have what I think is probably the correctly filled grid, but there are several clues I don't fully understand.

Grid:

> [image]

Answers and brief explanations:

Across:

> 1, 28. **DOWN FOR THE COUNT** *ddef, kinda* Out cold after making reservations for nobleman (perhaps a Transylvanian) (4,3,3,5)
> 6, 29. **KINE and KITH** *ddef* Neat following for family radio stations in Hawaii (4 and 4)
> 10. **SPLIT** *(A POLTERGEIST GENTLY - TOTAL ENERGY EG)** Separate and Extract total energy e.g. from a poltergeist, gently? (5)
> 11. **PHNOM PENH** *PH(-a)NTOM PEN + H(-oward) - (-lovecraf)T* Phantom pen crossing out a character with the beginnings of Howard Lovecraft ending avoided in The Pearl of Asia (5, 4)
> 12, 22. **SILVER BULLET** *SIL(-en)T containing VERB U L LE; one def at each end, wordplay in the middle* Film, Silent, (no English). In it a word of action, for all to see: "Hand the French a solution to everything" (6, 6)
> 13. **MORITA** *this is very doubtful; see below* Morticia with cousin turned back? See yours truly leaving with early player? (6)
> 14. **MANFREDA** *MANFRED + A* Byron's Poem a succulent piece of history. (8)
> 18. **RAFFIA** *AFFAIR** Palm reading reveals affair (6)
> 20. **BALLADED** *DEADBALL** Sang perhaps of Lenore, reviving dead ball (8)
> 23. **AMELIA** *triple def* Gothic novelist and doctors assistant? That might be why limbs are missing. (6)
> 27. **ALEPH NULL**; *(DOWN DALE AND UP HILL - ODD DAWN I)** Cursed down dale, and up hill without odd dawn I might correspond to something natural. (5,4)
> 30. **CHEAT DEATH** *(HE CREATED THE PORTRAIT CURSE - PICTURE RESTORER)** Lacking picture restorer, he created the portrait curse (unwittingly) to remain alive against all odds (5, 5)

Down:

> 1. **DOSES** *DO + (SEANCES-CANE*)* Gives a drug to perform seances! Spare the cane please. (5)
> 2. **WOLFSON** *spoonerism of SOLF WON* Sir Isaac & Spooner's resistance circle victorious. (7)
> 3. **FATAL** *(-vic)T(-ors) in FA(-ntastic)AL* Tragic victors heart inserted into fantastical shell (5)
> 4. **REPLEADS** *RE PLEAIDES minus (-po)E and (-henr)I* Re: Pleaides, Poe (Henri, lately) leaves and makes another bargain. (8)
> 7. **ICEPICK** *ICE + PICK* Chilling selection for lobotomy technique? (7)
> 8. **ENHEARSED** *(EN(-d) HEARS(-y))* plus D and ... also an E for reasons I don't understand* Mostly end hears'y, some dead scattered within and lowered into coffin. (9)
> 9. **IMMORTAL** *IMMORAL containing T* Hedonistic model taken in; Dorian Grey perhaps and might be way to 30ac. (8)
> 14. **MARY BLACK** *(BARKER ALCHEMY - HERE)** Barker with alchemy, lies here forgotten, but another on trial was released after repining neck cloth. (4, 5)
> 15. **RAISE THE STAKES** *ddef* Get ready to kill vampire, it's how one increases risk (5,3,6)
> 17. **CARMILLA** *initial letters ("sinisterly")* Carriage accident reveals mysterious individual, leaving Laura amorous, sinisterly and seen in a glass darkly. (8)
> 19. **FULGENT** *def + p.d. + p.d. indicator; "needful gentlewoman"* Bright framing of ghostly needlewoman? What devilry is this? (7)
> 21. **DRACULA** *not sure exactly why; see below* Felix and Bella: "Perhaps flowers, including a Lily and the other side of the rose, have a sublime range of colours?" (7)
> 24. **LACED** *two defs + (-p)LACED* Perhaps blood in drinks, shirts or boots, placed disquietingly? (5)
> 25., 5. **WITCH HUNT** *cryptic def referencing torture device* Search perhaps conducted by the press? (5-4)
> 26. **HUSH** *HU(-mani)SH* Silent episode featuring gentlemen with human-ish exterior. (4)

Things I don't fully understand:

> 13a is kinda baffling. My best guess, which I don't believe, is that the answer is MORITA, obtained by taking MORTICIA, reversing IT (though I believe the actual name of the character this would be referencing is "Cousin Itt", with two Ts) to get MORITCIA, removing C+I ("see yours truly leaving") to get MORITA; "early player" would then be the def; there are many Japanese people called Morita, some of whom play games or instruments, but none of them jumps out at me as being defined by "*early* player".
>  I'm not sure who the second def in 23a is. Fielding's title character, perhaps? (First is Amelia Beauclerc. Third is indeed the dictionary definition of "amelia".)
>  21d is clearly DRACULA; *D. felix* and *D. bella* are two species of orchid, so "Felix and Bella, perhaps, flowers" can be the definition, but I don't understand the wordplay. I wondered about something to do with *Dranunculus*, a genus of lilies, but don't see how to make it work.

Things I didn't fully understand but now think I do thanks to helpful comments from people cleverer than me:

> It was clear that 2dn is a spoonerism of *something* WON but I couldn't figure out what. oAlt points out the existence of the "Solf Circle", a group of German intellectuals opposed to Nazism.
>  I was mystified by the gentlement in 26d. oAlt points out the existence of a *Buffy* episode titled "Hush" featuring adversaries called "The Gentlemen" who take away people's voices.

Things I said "I don't fully understand" about in an earlier version of this answer, but that were really more quibbles about clue construction (but it is possible in each case that I am in fact failing to understand something and there's nothing wrong with the clue):

> 6a,29a seems like the "following" is backwards; KITH is following KINE, not vice versa. Also, I can't help wondering whether there's some sort of reference to the phrase "kith and kin" going on here, but if so I don't quite see how it works.
>  18a seems to be an anagram with no anagram indicator, and I'm not sure what "reading" is doing in the clue.
>  17d seems like it's missing an "in" in the definition; *Carmilla* is one of the stories in *In A Glass Darkly* by Sheridan Le Fanu.

Comment: This is the correct filling, let me know if want any of these explained.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm not going to figure out any of the ones I haven't already figured out, but I suggest waiting a bit for other PSE denizens to be smarter than me and feel smug :-). But after, say, a day or two I would be very glad to have any gaps filled.

Comment: (The ones for which I'm fairly sure I'm missing something, as opposed to there being minor inaccuracies in the cluing, are 13a, 23a, 2d, 21d, 26d.)

Comment: (cc: @AncientSwordRage ) 26d seems to be a reference to [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hush_(Buffy_the_Vampire_Slayer))

Comment: For 2d, the resistance circle might be [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solf_Circle)

Comment: @oAlt No "might" about it, that's gotta be right. And you're clearly right about 26d too, though it seems like the clue is a bit sloppy in that case (the episode isn't actually silent, and "silent" can't quite be a definition because it's the wrong part of speech). (Aaaaaaaaaah! A sloppy clue! How terrifying!)

Comment: Is now a good time to reveal more explanations?

Comment: Yup. I would be glad to understand more...

Comment: 13a rot13(Cng Zbevgn cynlf Whony Rneyl va va Qrfreg Urng) this was definitely a stretch and not  a fair one. I also did mess up the cousin's name.

Comment: 23a. rot13(Nzryvn Cbaq (pbzzbayl xabj nf Nzl Cbaq) vf bar bs Qbpgbe Jub'f pbzcnavbaf/nffvfgnagf)

Comment: 21d rot13(Yvyl Qenphyn vf  n punenpgre sebz Gur Zhafgref (1964) naq Gur Ebfr vf gur O-Fvqr gb Pynj Oblf Pynj "Qenphyn"/"Gur Ebfr") I got a little carried away in clueing everything that wasn't the obvious answer.

Comment: 6a,29a it's possible I got these switched around by accident, something I should have checked. It's a phrase I associated with rot13(Gur ebyrcynlvat tnzr Inzcver: Gur Znfdhrenqr naq Inzcver: gur Erdhvrz) but by the time I realised it wasn't that common a phrase it was a little late to fit something else.

Comment: 18a the anagram indicator is non-standard but supposed to be 'reading reveals'. And 17d, yes I think there is an 'in' missing here.

Comment: "Kin and kith" or "kith and kin" is plenty common enough but (1) it's "kin" not "kine" and (2) there's no definition of that phrase at either end of the clue. So far as I can tell the def is the thing about radio stations. I don't think I've ever before seen a crossword clue whose answer is just the call-signs of two radio stations, though :-).

Comment: Thanks for all the explanations!

Comment: MW on [Kith](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kith) and [Kine](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kine), Wiktionary on the [(archaic) phrase](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/kith_and_kine#English).

Comment: Hmm. I have never ever heard "kith and kine" before and the OED has never heard of it (but _has_ heard of "kith and kin"). How sure are you that this is a real thing rather than someone making up a plausible-sounding etymology on Wiktionary?

Comment: The brief discussion on the discussion tab of that Wiktionary page seems to fit with my suspicions, too...

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I've definitely seen it used in a roleplaying game, however I don't have that book any more. It's likely that it was either lifted from that eggcorn, or a similar pun was made by the game developers.